# GetDIBits не возращает пиксели

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, скриншот

Я пытаюсь использовать следующий код, для получения скриншота выбранного окна

```
void GetWindowScreen(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hdcW = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcW);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};// = new BITMAPINFO();

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcW, width, height);

    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width*height;

    HBITMAP old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, hdcW, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, old);

    delete[] imgbytearr;
    imgbytearr = new unsigned char [width*height*4];

    GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, height, imgbytearr, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    imgsize[0][0] = width;
    imgsize[0][1] = height;

    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcW);
}
```

Однако, каждый раз, imgbytearr остаётся пустым. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0
```

или правильно указать

```
width*height*4;
```

Comment: Сделал, не помогло.

Comment: Если вызвать с null вместо буфера - возвращает размер буфера?

Comment: Да, при вызове вместе с null, в bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage возвращается ожидаемый размер изображения.

Comment: Если после этого выделить буфер такого размера, и второй раз вызвать с ним - работает?

Comment: Нет, массив imgbytearr по прежнему остаётся пустым

Comment: Прошу прощения, перепроверил, кажется всё заработало. Благодарю за помощь.